# IntelliJ IDEA (Linux): Go to beginning/end of line

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have switched from OS X to Linux, and trying to get used to the different keyboard shortcuts in IDEA. One very important thing I cannot find is **"move cursor to beginning/end of line" (Cmd-Left and Cmd-Right on OS X).** Also looking at the [reference card](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) doesn't reveal anything useful.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but in most of the editors you can simply use the "Home" and "End" buttons for that.

Comment: On the MacBook Pro keyboard this corresponds to Fn - Cursor-Left and Fn - Cursor-Right. Usually I hate the Fn key, but I have just tried this combination and it works quite well. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

If anyone else is wondering this 2 1/5+ years after it was answered like I was, you have to hit Fn + either left or right arrows.

I just switched to Ubuntu and relied HEAVILY on the command button and its killing me now that everything is so different.

Comment: While `end` is useful, I hate reaching all the way up to the upper right of my keyboard.   This answer is much better and should be the selected answer.  I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 6):

You can go to the beginning or end of the line using **`Home`** and **`End`**.
But I set some shortcuts for these actions.

First, go to **`Settings > Keymap`**

Search one of the following in the search box and set a shortcut for it. For example, I used these shortcuts:

- Move Caret to Line End **`Alt + L`**
- Move Caret to Line Start **`Alt + J`**

**Additional shortcuts:**

- Move Caret to Link End with Selection **`Alt + Shift + L`**
- Move Caret to Link Start with Selection **`Alt + Shift + J`**
- Add Selection for Next Occurrence **`Alt + E`**
- Unselect Occurrence **`Alt + Shift + E`**

Answer (score 0):

For me, on Ubuntu, it is Fn+Home, Fn+End to move to beginning and end of line.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled my IntelliJ and since IdeaVIM plugin was not installed I decide to just google how to do that with IntelliJ defaults and I gotta tell ya... Fn+Home/Fn+Arrow is not convenient in a slightest

Two possible answers:

1. Install the IdeaVIM plugin (You should not do that if you are not familiar with VIM)
2. Remap those keys to something that is easier to access

Answer (score 0):

Quick update:

if you are using the latest Intellij IDE version, pressing the `Ende` or the  `Pos1` buttons will achieve your needs. btw I am using a German keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can just do

```
Fn + <- // To move to the beginning of the line
Fn + -> // To move to the end of the line
```